# event not showing on android device calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, background-service

We are working on android application, we are trying to add event in background service silently. Using below code for the same:

```
package com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Reminders;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

import com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MyService extends BackgroundService {

    private final static String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

    private String mHelloTo = "World";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doWork() {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();



            Log.d(TAG, "Start calendar insertion");

            JSONObject jsonArray;

            long calID = 3;
            long startMillis = 0; 
            long endMillis = 0;     
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.set(2014, 9, 14, 7, 30);
            startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(2014, 9, 14, 8, 45);
            endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();


            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
            values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
            values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
            values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
            values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
            values.put(Events.VISIBLE, 0);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
            Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
            long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());




            Log.d(TAG, "End calendar insertion");


        return result;  
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject getConfig() {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        try {
            result.put("HelloTo", this.mHelloTo);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setConfig(JSONObject config) {
        try {
            if (config.has("HelloTo"))
                this.mHelloTo = config.getString("HelloTo");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

    }     

    @Override
    protected JSONObject initialiseLatestResult() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTimerEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onTimerDisabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

This code is returning an EVENTID that means it is adding event to device calendar, but no event is showing on calendar.
What could we do to show that added event on device's calendar?

Comment: Do you have the     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
 permissions?

Comment: @Wildcopper yes this is already added.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my code (including a "forced sync" at the end) to open and write in the calendar. Maybe you can find your answer in there, it works flawlessly.

```
import java.util.Date;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Calendars;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;

public class TVCalendar {

    public static final String TAG = "TVCalendar";

    // Projection array. Creating indices for this array instead of doing
    // dynamic lookups improves performance.
    public static final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Calendars._ID,                           // 0
        Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                  // 1
        Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,         // 2
        Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT                  // 3
    };

    // The indices for the projection array above.
    private static final int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int PROJECTION_ACCOUNT_NAME_INDEX = 1;
    private static final int PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX = 2;
    private static final int PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX = 3;

    static public class CalendarEntry {
        String  room;
        String  name;
        Date    start;
        Date    end;
        String  description;
        public CalendarEntry (String pRoom, String pName, Date pStart, Date pEnd, String pDesc) {
            room=pRoom;
            name=pName;
            start=pStart;
            end=pEnd;
            description=pDesc;
        }
    }

    static String   lastCalName="";
    static long     lastCalId=-1;

    static public long openCalendar(String calName,String owner) {
        if ((lastCalId>0) && (lastCalName.equals(calName)))
            return lastCalId;
        // Run query
        TVLog.i(TAG, "Querying Calendar "+calName+" owned by "+owner);
        Cursor cur = null;
        ContentResolver cr = TVPrefs.mainActivity.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Calendars.CONTENT_URI;   
//      String selection = "((" + Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) AND (" 
//                              + Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?) AND ("
//                              + Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + " = ?))";
//      String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {owner, "com.google",
//              owner}; 
        // Submit the query and get a Cursor object back. 
        cur = cr.query(uri, EVENT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        // Use the cursor to step through the returned records
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            long calID = 0;
            String displayName = null;
            String accountName = null;
            String ownerName = null;

            // Get the field values
            calID = cur.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX);
            displayName = cur.getString(PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX);
            accountName = cur.getString(PROJECTION_ACCOUNT_NAME_INDEX);
            ownerName = cur.getString(PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX);

            TVLog.i(TAG, "Display: "+displayName+" Account: "+accountName+" Owner: "+ownerName);

            if (displayName.equals(calName)) {
                lastCalId=calID;
                lastCalName=calName;
                return calID;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }

    static public boolean addEvent(String calName, String ownerName, String timeZone, CalendarEntry entry) {
        long    calId=openCalendar(calName,ownerName);
        TVLog.i(TAG, "Calendar ID: "+calId);
        if (calId>=0) {
            // Write to the Calendar
            ContentResolver cr = TVPrefs.mainActivity.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Events.DTSTART, entry.start.getTime());
            values.put(Events.DTEND, entry.end.getTime());
            values.put(Events.TITLE, entry.name);
            values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, entry.description);
            values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calId);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, entry.room);
            values.put(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PUBLIC);
            //Uri uri 
            cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            // Force a sync
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
            extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
            AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(TVPrefs.mainActivity);
            Account[] acc = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
            Account account = null;
            if (acc.length>0) {
                account=acc[0];
                ContentResolver.requestSync(account, "com.android.calendar", extras);
            }

            return true;

            // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
            // long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods are static btw, don't use it "as is", it's special for my application.

Comment: Although this works but one strange issue, now events appear as birthday in calender !!!